# Spring integration with spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

Please let me know , when i am putting say 5 files in a directory , 5 messages gets generated by the poller , i want that the spring batch job will get triggered only one time, not five times ,if the files are coming together say within 1 min duration. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use an [Aggregator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator) for this kind of task. So, you will collect several files together by expected size or withing some time window. You need to use some static `correlationKey` to let the component to group files.

When the group is ready, a single message is emitted and you are good to trigger a Batch job for this set of files.

Comment: Thanks Artem , will look into